# How to Implement Resizing in CSS / DOM

Tags: javascript, css, dom

### Context

On OSX, I notice that if I take my mouse cursor and drag it to the border (bottom, left, or right), the cursor changes to from regular pointer to resize cursor (<->) when:

- I am inside the window, but within 4-5 pixels of the border
- I am outside of the window, but within 4-5 pixels of the border

### Question

Now, I note that in CSS/DOM, I have the "on mouse over" event -- how would I implement something like this in CSS / DOM / JavaScript?

Would the correct approach be:

- create some type of "invisible border" that is not shown, and also not contribute to the window size?
- do some type of complicated manual mouse tracking to know when I'm close to the border (since I also need to handle when the mouse cursor is outside of the border)
- does CSS have some type of "mouse near border" rather than "on mouse over" event?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean drag (a la "click down and drag") or hover (no click)?

Comment: Well, this was based on an answer that was posted by @undefined earlier but then deleted (not sure why). Is this demonstrative of what you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/V5h5F/1/

Comment: @Jared: If you post that as an answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an approach I refined from one originally posted by undefined (another user) which was subsequently deleted for some reason. By no means should this be interpreted as a final approach, but it shows how you could create a bounding box with left/right/top/bottom handles, all added by CSS.

**HTML**

```
<div id='container' class='boundary top-bottom'>
  <div class='boundary left-right'>
    <div class='contents'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 50px;
}
.contents {
    cursor: default;
    background: green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.boundary {
    background: blue;
    padding: 10px;
}
.boundary.top-bottom {
    cursor: row-resize;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
.boundary.left-right {
    cursor: col-resize;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    width: 280px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/V5h5F/1/

Handling something like needing a border and invisible overlaps would require some retooling, probably using something like Javascript and the internal `boundary` being the border; the complexity of doing that in pure CSS is problematic I think (undefined's answer handled this with `position`ed elements on the boundaries).